# Are there any key value system in post message in iframe communication

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, iframe

My iframe Code 
Link is http://example.org?pd=123

```
            var currentHeight = $('.comments_holder').outerHeight();
            var parent = window.parent;
            var targetOrigin = "my parent site link";
            if (parent && parent.postMessage) {
                parent.postMessage(currentHeight, targetOrigin);
            }
```

From this i need to pass the height of the div to the main site

And now i also want to pass another parameter to main site

```
                var count = 123;
                var parent = window.parent;
                var targetOrigin = "my parent site link";
                if (parent && parent.postMessage) {
                    parent.postMessage(count , targetOrigin);
                }
```

And my code in main site i.e. `single.php` of wordpress site

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{

what will if else condition here to get both the values 

} 

});
</script>
```

**NOTE i cant check based on event.origin as the link are containing parameters 
for eg `example.com?pd=123`**

And this link could be changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd pass the set of items through as an object:

```
parent.postMessage({'height': currentHeight, 'stuff': 'foo'}, targetOrigin);
```

In your example "event.data" would contain the passed object. For example:

```
function receiveMessage(event) {
   console.log(event.data.height);
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage#The_dispatched_event for more detail.

Comment: but i want to post current height three times and stuff : foo only once

Comment: Lots of ways to do this... for example you could pass an extra field to postMessage signifying its "type": postMessage({'type': 'height', 'height': currentHeight'},...) or postMessage({'type': 'foo', 'foo': 'value'}, ...); Then just inspect event.data.type in receiveMessage and do the right thing.

Comment: I am getting undefined in console for event.data.type

Comment: i am using chrome browser

Comment: What does your postMessage call look like?